# Oracle PL/SQL select into variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am trying to run the following query in SQL Developer, but I am receiving an error.  I am trying to declare two local variables (var_num1 and payDate) and then set the variables.  Does anyone know what I can be doing incorrectly?  I know Oracle SQL is a little different than SQL Server.

```
DECLARE
  var_num1 number; 
  payDate date;
 BEGIN 
  var_num1 := 100; 
  payDate := '10/1/2013'
  BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM Paycode WHERE PaycodeID = var_num1 and PaycodeDate = payDate;
  End;
END;
```

---

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 2:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: That's a PL/SQL block, not a query.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use SELECT without INTO clause in PL/SQL. The output of the SELECT must be stored somewhere. Eg. table or variable or perhaps a record. See example below how to store result of the SELECT statement into record.

```
DECLARE
  var_num1 number; 
  payDate date;
  v_result Paycode%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  var_num1 := 100; 
  payDate := '10/1/2013';

    SELECT * INTO v_result
    FROM Paycode
    WHERE PaycodeID = var_num1 and PaycodeDate = payDate;

END;
```

Comment: THank you for your response.  Is "v_result" a variable or a table?  I do not want to create a table.

Comment: It is basically a row stored inside variable (some might call that object). It is common way to store content of whole row when selecting all columns in the table (using *), see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32plsql-1578019.html

Comment: Oh great, so it is not actually creating a physical row or table?  This is just stored in memory while the query is being executed, correct?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I try this, the result is "annoymous block completed", it doesn't actually select the result.

Comment: @user3083460 It ran the `select` statement. You just didn't do anything useful with the result.

Comment: How do I do something with the select statement?  I want to get the results just like a normal select statement.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If by "get the results" you mean output them to the screen, you could use dbms_output (and make sure SQL Developer has the option to show dbms_output turned on). Please note that PL/SQL isn't really meant to be used interactively, necessarily. You would probably be better served by executing that query as normal SQL using SQL Developer.

Comment: I am using SQL Developer, I just want to make my query as interactively as possible.  ex in SQL Server/ DECLARE num int SET num = 1 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = num..I need this type of query in SQL Developer..thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in _bind variables_. They are preceded by a colon, e.g. `select * from my_table where id = :id_var`. If you run that sort of query, SQL Developer should prompt you for the value to use (for :id_var in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a resultset back in SQL Developer with this code block you will need to open a ref cursor for the query e.g.

```
DECLARE
  refCur REF CURSOR;
  refc refCur;
  var_num1 number; 
  payDate date;
  v_result Paycode%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  var_num1 := 100; 
  payDate := '10/1/2013';

OPEN refc FOR
    SELECT * 
    FROM Paycode
    WHERE PaycodeID = var_num1 and PaycodeDate = payDate;

END;
```