# How to use variable of declare at the where of select?

Tags: oracle11g

How to use variable of declare at the where of select ?

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL);

insert into student VALUES(10,'AA','A01');
insert into student VALUES(30,'BB','B01');
```

---MSSQL OK

```
declare @v_first  varchar(10);
set @v_first='AA';
select * from student where first_name=@v_first;
```

---ORACLE --ERROR

```
declare v_first varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  v_first :='AA';
  select * from student where first_name= v_first;
END;
```

---=> MESSAGE

ORA-06550: line 4 ,  column 3 : 
PLS-00428: 在此 SELECT 敘述句中預期會出現一個 INTO 子句
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you gave for MSSQL is a different table, but assuming DEPT_ID from USER_LIST is a NUMBER too...  SQL will automatically convert the string to compare...

You need to cast the id to a number. Is there a reason you are declaring a varchar variable right before comparing it against a number?

```
 declare v_id varchar2(2);
    BEGIN
      v_id :='30';
      select * from student where id= TO_NUMBER(v_id);    
    END;
```

or change the declare and the assignment...

```
declare v_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_id :=30;
  select * from student where id= v_id;

END;
```

basically, what the link I added in the comments below said..  from user tvm.. "You cannot use SELECT without INTO clause in PL/SQL. The output of the SELECT must be stored somewhere. Eg. table or variable or perhaps a record. See example below how to store result of the SELECT statement into record."

```
DECLARE
  v_id number; 
  v_result Student%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  v_id := 30; 

    SELECT * INTO v_result
    FROM Student
    WHERE id = v_id;
END;
```

Then you need to do something with v_result... other option shown is to call straight SQL - all depends on how you call and consume the data..

Comment: Whew - it has been a while since I've done Oracle, so I had to look...  I found this other questions and answer on SO for you to look at - since I don't know how you are trying to call this query in oracle or what you want to do with the results, it explains why this isn't working for you and how you can use it. [plsql into](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474612/oracle-pl-sql-select-into-variables)

Comment: Dear：Thx for your hlep. I use MSSQL ，when I try to create a proc,I will try it step by step, So I want to see the result of the where xx=variable .     so IN Oracle ,I must use into v_result,But how to show the v_result directlly?  I hust start learn racle, so they are many secipt I can't find out . thx

Comment: And the Student%ROWTYPE just can resive 1 result?

Comment: I find ,I msust use  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_result.first_name ||'--'|| v_result.last_name);  to get column one by one, Can i get them with select?

Comment: you can select them into separate variables, so Select first_name, last_name into v_first_name, v_last_name from student... etc..  Did you look at the link I provided in the first comment?  back to another question and great answers about this?  read through the comments and answers - gives you a couple ways to do it and also a link to this [oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32plsql-1578019.html)

Comment: Dear RandomShelly：THX FOR YOUR HELP,I am sorry doesn't see the link of plsql ino at that time,I will try to learn those article step by step.